# Access file system from applet without signing

Tags: java, applet, trusted-sites

In a trusted domain, is it possible to access the file system from an applet without signing the the applet?

Comment: [Java tutorial on what applets can and can't do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

Comment: @AndrewThompson ok - out of interest do you have a reference?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I believe the tutorial has been rewritten to take this into account. In the page I linked to, there is a specific section for unsigned applets launched via JNLP. Unless I'm missing something here...

Comment: @assylias Oh my bad!  I completely missed that 4th paragraph that covers it.  Sorry for the confusion.  :P

Comment: What is a 'trusted domain'? An unsigned applet can read from and write to the local file system of the user if 1) It is deployed in a plug-in 2 JRE. 2) It uses the JNLP API FileService 3) The user OKs the action when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

No. I think the applet must have the signature. Why don't sign your applet with the same cert your trusted domain are?